# C# Building an Action Expression with a code block

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I am tying to build an Expression tree that would represent this lambda:

```
Action<TFrom, TTo> map = 
    (from, to) => 
    {
        to.Property1 = (Nullable<TTo>)from.Property1;
        to.Property2 = (Nullable<TTo>)from.Property2;
        // ...continued for all properties
    };
```

Essentially, I am trying to map the non-nullable properties from one class to the `Nullable<T>` properties of another class that share the same property name.

I have written this (incorrect) tree in my attempt to do this:

```
SomeObjWithOutNullable i = new SomeObjWithOutNullable(); // Not "object".. doh
SomeObjWithNullable j = new SomeObjWithNullable();

ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeObjWithOutNullable), "from");
ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeObjWithNullable), "to");

MemberExpression m1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(p1, "Property1");
MemberExpression m2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(p2, "Property1");
BinaryExpression body = Expression.Assign(m1, m2);
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<SomeObjWithOutNullable,SomeObjWithNullable>>(body, new[] { p1,p2 });

var action = lambda.Compile();
action(i,j);
```

This does not compile. I get this exception when I attempt to:

```
Delegate 'System.Action<SomeObjWithOutNullable,SomeObjWithNullable>' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'SomeObjWithNullable'
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'object' to 'SomeObjWithNullable'
```

I know I have yet to add in the type conversion, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do even the assignment correctly.

Comment: Currently the expressions you've written out generate: `(from, to) => new SomeObjWithOutNullable().Property1 = new SomeObjWithNullable().Property2;`  That's pretty far off from the code that you think you're writing...

Comment: Yes, I fixed that typo. I suppose the question relates more to the assignment itself. Once I can get that part down, I can work out the remainder.

Comment: You haven't edited the question at all, so apparently you *haven't* fixed that issue.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your first comment. I see (so far) where I'm going wrong, though I am still running into trouble. My understanding of Expression trees is very limited.

Comment: If you have an answer post it as an *answer*, not as an edit to the quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution:

```
void NullPropertyConvertionAction<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target)
{
    var sourceDictionary = typeof(TSource).GetProperties()
        .ToDictionary(s => 
            s.Name.
            StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
        );
    ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "from");
    ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), "to");
    var expressionBodies = new List<BinaryExpression>();
    foreach (var member in typeof(TTarget).GetProperties()
        .Where(p=> p.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
        && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        if (sourceDictionary.ContainsKey(member.Name))
        {
            MemberExpression m1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(p1, sourceDictionary[member.Name].Name);
            MemberExpression m2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(p2, member.Name);
            BinaryExpression body = Expression.Assign(m2, Expression.Convert(m1, member.PropertyType));
            expressionBodies.Add(body);
        }
    }
    BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(expressionBodies.ToArray());   
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<TSource,TTarget (block, new[] { p1,p2 });
    Action<TSource,TTarget> action = (Action<TSource,TTarget>)lambda.Compile();
    action(source,target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've thrown away the type information when you downcast your lambda to `LambdaExpression`. The easiest way to solve this would be to use `var`:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda ...
```

Alternatively, use the full correct type:

```
Expression<Action<TSource, TTarget>> lambda = Expression.Lambda ...
```